# Changing Wordpress Theme in Staging Environment

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, mysql-backup

I have a live  newspaper WordPress website with about 10 users updating it daily with about 2000+ unique visitors a day. I have a sum of about 30 posts a day added to my db and i host my own pictures.

My goal is to change my theme that has been used for over 4 years so smoothly that I don't experience much hiccup for my viewers.

I want a dev environment somewhere in my server that I can test my new theme with my current posts.

A solution I have in my head is to create a subdomain for example "dev.example.com" and deploy the new theme there and have two working wordpress themes with one database.

Is this even possible? I need to have my new theme that is in a dev environment have access to my live database.

What is the best practice for this situation?

Comment: You just clone the whole site and put it in  a different domain (or subdomain) and pointing to a dev database (no sharing of DB between dev and production please!!). There are a lot of guides online about how you can do this. You might need to do a search/replace to fix links in posts that go to the live site. When a change is ready, you can copy it to your production server. I would **STRONGLY** suggest you to use a version control system like GIT to track your changes and deploy them to your production server.

Comment: for the dev database what do you think about cloning my own db and pointing dev env to the clone db? would you suggest that? a wordpress installation on subdomain wont conflict with a wordpress installation on my live website?

Comment: It shouldn't affect the main site. But please do check some tutorials online, there are a few steps you have to do and depending on your hosting they will be different. For example: create DNS entry, add a new subdomain in your hosting, map the subdomain so apache can serve it, create new DB and restore it, etc, etc. And like with any software, please do have a backup of your production site in case you click on the wrong button and nuke it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

for people  looking into this like me, I will post my findings below and if you like you can comment to guide me or tell me what I'm doing wrong or right.

- there is a [wp-staging plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/) that can be used but it seems to be paid if you want to push changes from staging version to production version of your website.
- I have also figured out that another wp website can be installed on a subdomain that you can create through cpanel and install a brand new wordpress environment that is completely separate from your live site with its own db and config.
- Since most of us don't have unlimited server resources its going to be pretty heavy to clone everything from live site to staging site and I figured they cant share a db because changes made to staging site can effect live site if they share a database.
- So I looked over a very well summarized easy [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWgsfJtyG-c) which basically explained the whole process for cloning your wordpress on your subdomain and using a new db, but this solution can be good if you have the server space and resources, for a website like mine i would guess that a local installation of wordpress would work.
- One of the comments on that video was very usefull as well:

> Just create a subdomain, install WordPress with Softaculous on the subdomain, install the All In One WP Migration Plugin on both the main site and the subdomain, export the file in [All In One WP Migration](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) on the main site and import it to the subdomain and vice versa, you have your staging.